# How to validate a username / password via JQuery / Ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Trying to get this to work for sometime now:

```
<input id="usr_login_attp" value="ok" />

function check_for_acc() { 
 $("#usr_login_attp").val("ok");
 jQuery.ajax({
   url: "http://localhost:3000/login/validate_user/", 
   type: 'POST',
   dataType: 'json',
   data: {'email':$('#user_email').val(), 'password':$('#user_password').val(), 'authenticity_token': jQuery('input[name="authenticity_token"]').val()},
   error: function(xhr_data) {
     //sdfsd
   },
   success: function(xhr_data) {
     $("#usr_login_attp").val(xhr_data.status);
   }
 });
}

check_for_acc();
if ($("#usr_login_attp").val() == "fail") {
  err++;
  errStr += "Email or Password Was Not Recognized<br />";
}
```

The ajax function is updating the `$("#usr_login_attp")` field with either "ok" or "fail", this part is working ok, however when I call `check_for_acc()`, the following if statement fails to pass everytime, regardless of what the actual value of `$("#usr_login_attp")` is?

This is driving me nuts, can anyone see what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yep! You're thinking that the `success` handler will execute before the rest of your script does. That's almost certainly incorrect.

The processing of the login success/failure needs to happen within the callback. Once you call `check_for_acc()`, it makes the Ajax call--but the callback doesn't get called until the Ajax call completes. Meanwhile, your code runs merrily along.

Alternatively, you could use the [`jQuery.when()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/) function to wrap up some of that hoop jumping for you.