# Trying to call PHP script from Javascript If statement

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, validation

I have a form which gets validated by javascript. In one of the if statements, in the final condition (when everything else has been validated) I would like to put my PHP script that updates SQL with one of the passwords.

This is the final validation:

```
function passwordCheck() {
    var password = '<?php echo $password; ?>';
    if (document.passwordform.inputedPassword.value == password)
    {
        if (document.passwordform.Password1.value == document.passwordform.Password2.value)
        {
            *********************************************************
        } else 
        {
            document.getElementById("equalpasswords1").innerHTML = "Passwords should be equal";
            document.getElementById("equalpasswords2").innerHTML = "Passwords should be equal";
        }
    } else 
    {
        text = "Insert a correct password";
        document.getElementById("editpassword").innerHTML = text;
    }
    return true;
}
```

And I would like to insert a call to my PHP script where the stars are. How could I do this? I read that you can't insert PHP into javascript, so it has to be an external PHP file. My SQL update code is this one:

```
<?php              
$x = $_POST['Password2'];

define('DB_NAME', 'Students');
define('DB_USER', 'Students');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'Password');
define('DB_HOST','HOST');

$link = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);

if (!link) {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

$db_selected = mysql_select_db(DB_NAME, $link);

if (!$db_selected) {
  die('Can\'t use'. DB_NAME. ': ' . mysql_error());
}    


$result = "UPDATE  `1956218_students`.`Students` SET  `Password` =  '$x' WHERE  `Students`.`StudEmail` = '$email'  ";
if (!mysql_query($result)) {
die('error: ' .mysql_error());
} 

?>
```

Comment: You have to use AJAX.

Comment: This is open to SQL injections as well.

Comment: You're trying to get people to enter their current password, but yet you echo the password in plain text to the page... What are you trying to prevent there? Also you are vulnerable to SQL injection and you should be hashing your passwords.

Comment: Please don't mind about SQL injection and plain text, I'll work on that later. I just want to get this working for now

Comment: Do what you want, but in general that is a bad way to code. First, it's significantly easier when you have something fresh on your mind to just do it right the first time around. Second, you may actually completely forget to go back and do something. Third, if you do remember to fix it, you're still doing double the work than just doing it right in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

You need to realize that JavaScript is being executed at client's side (in browser), while the PHP code is being executed at server's side.

So you need to make another request to the server, so that PHP codes can handle / process it (validate the password, prepare some response - ideally in JSON format etc.).

You might want to do something like:
[How to validate a username / password via JQuery / Ajax?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8059777/1168156)